# how can i increase any number

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, repeater

I used repeater and I want to increase `htmlcaption1` like `htmlcaption2`, `htmlcaption3` .... :

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterBigBanner" runat="server">  
    <HeaderTemplate>  

    </HeaderTemplate>  
    <ItemTemplate>
         <img src="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BannerPath")%>"alt="#htmlcaption1""  />
    </ItemTemplate>

    <SeparatorTemplate>  

    </SeparatorTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

cs side:

```
sqlConn.Open();
            sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
            sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn;            
            sqlComm.CommandText = "select Top(11) * from BannerYonetim where GosterimYeri='W' and Aktif=0 and BaslangicTarihi<getdate() and BitisTarihi>getdate() order by BaslangicTarihi";       
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
            RepeaterBigBanner.DataSource = myDataSet;
            RepeaterBigBanner.DataBind();
```

How can I increase `alt="#htmlcaption1"` like : `#htmlcaption2`, `#htmlcaption3` ... `#htmlcaption11`?

Thanks your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
<ItemTemplate>
         <img src="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BannerPath")%>" alt="<%# "#htmlcaption" + (Container.ItemIndex + 1).ToString() %>"  />
</ItemTemplate>
```

i don't find it very usefull to specify an alt in that case though... or at least not a different one as it doesn't describe the image.